# Reorder lines in each 3-line record

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

I have a file which contains lots of records in following manner.

```
Name
Address
Phone
```

This is the sequence for each record in that file. Now, I want to copy this file to other file with changed order as below.

```
Address
Phone
Name
```

How to write shell script to do this?

Comment: what is the delimiter between records?

Comment: They are line by line

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
sed -n 'h;n;p;n;G;p' < file.in > file.out
```

For example:

```
$ seq 9 | sed -n 'h;n;p;n;G;p'
2
3
1
5
6
4
8
9
7
```

Comment: Thanks Stephane. It's working fine for single record in the file, but getting different output than expected if I have multiple records in file.

Comment: OK, sorry, see edit.

Comment: It's perfect now.

Comment: Terrific! Can you please explain what's going on there (what does the character sequence mean)?

Comment: @try-catch-finally, hold next print next get print

Answer (score 2):

If I'm reading your question right, you want to take sequences of 3 lines from the file, and swap the order of the first and last in each? With GNU sed, you could do something like this I think:

```
sed -e :a -e '$!N' -e 's/\(.*\)\n\(.*\)\n\(.*\)$/\2\n\3\n\1/;Ta' file
```

which continually slurps up lines until it is able to make the swap, and then starts over.

Comment: @shinek ... well let's wait to see what the sed gurus have to say, I'm sure to have made a boo-boo somewhere ;)

Comment: You could use _first~step_ to golf it shorter: `sed '1~3{h;d};3~3G'`

Answer (score 1):

With `awk`:

```
awk '{l=$0;getline;print;getline;print $0"\n"l;}' < file_in > file_out
```

Explanation:

1. Save current record in variable `l`
2. Get next record using `getline`
3. Print that record (`print`, invoked without arguments will always
   print the current record)
4. Get the next record again using `getline`
5. Print that record, a newline and the first record stored in `l`
6. For the next record(s) start over at 1.

**References**

- awk [String Functions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html#tag_20_06_13_13)

Answer (score 0):

For some one-liner transformations, I like to use [`pyp`](https://pypi.org/project/pypyp/) (distributed as "pypyp").

### Unlabeled lines

If your lines are not labelled, you can do an unconditional transformation like so (%3: 0->2 1->0 2->1):

- `$ seq 9 | pyp '[elem for group in zip(lines[1::3],lines[2::3],lines[0::3]) for elem in group]'`

Shorter example output looks like this:

```bash
$ seq 6 | pyp '[elem for group in zip(lines[0::3],lines[2::3],lines[1::3]) for elem in group]'
1
3
2
4
6
5
```

### Labeled lines

Data setup:

```bash
$ pyp -b 'faker.Faker.seed(202418);f=faker.Faker()' \
  'json.dumps(
     [dict(name=f.first_name(),
        address=f.address().replace("\n",", "),
        phone=f.phone_number())
      for i in range(2)])' \
| jq '.[]|to_entries[]|(.key + ": " + .value)' -r \
| tee q202418.data
```

Parsing by prefix, not as robust as parsing into records:

```bash
$ <q202418.data \
  pyp -b 'f=lambda categ: filter(lambda l: l.startswith(categ), lines)' \
  'names=f("name:");
   addrs=f("address:");
   ps=f("phone:");
   [line for group in zip(addrs, ps, names) for line in group]'
```

For a discussion of more robust multi-line record parsing, see
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13295083/parsing-a-multi-line-data-file-with-python.

## Other pyp notes

pyp's `--explain` flag can help show what's happening, or allow you to save it as a standalone script:

```bash
$ seq 9 | pyp --explain '[elem for group in zip(lines[1::3],lines[2::3],lines[0::3]) for elem in group]'
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
from pyp import pypprint
lines = [x.rstrip('\n') for x in sys.stdin]
output = [elem for group in zip(lines[1::3], lines[2::3], lines[0::3]) for elem in group]
if output is not None:
    pypprint(output)
```

Pyp supports customization through a `PYP_CONFIG_FILE`.

pyp performs static analysis of the input code, some AST transformations and pruning, then compiles and executes the result, or with `--explain`, unparses the AST back to source. It imports packages from its environment, and errors early on unknown or undefined symbols.

See other usage examples at https://pypi.org/project/pypyp/.